# Retrofit 2 Returns Null When HTTP is 404

Tags: android, retrofit

I have API which works well. I return some http codes from API such as 200, 404 etc.

Whenever I get 404 http code from API, retrofit doesnt give me the response that I posted from API. As an example, I changed 404 code to 200 from API file and retrofit showed me. When code is 404, retrofit desn't give me the response body and returns null. I also tried to use `if(response.isSuccessful)` but didnt work.

Here is my retrofit code:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {


                switch (response.code()){
                    case 404:
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JsonElement successElement = response.body();
                        POJO_Response_Error_Message errorMessage;
                        errorMessage = gson.fromJson(successElement, POJO_Response_Error_Message.class);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR "+errorMessage.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case 200:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "200 success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // get response...
                        break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("error_log", "Retrofit error");
        }
    });
```

Error:

```
POJO_Response_Error_Message.getMessage()' on a null object reference
```

**SOLVE**:
I found alternative solution. My custom response was in Retrofit's errorBody itself.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
                   Type type = new TypeToken<POJO_Response_Error_Message>() {}.getType();
                   POJO_Response_Error_Message errorResponse = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().charStream(),type);
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESPONSE: "+errorResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: 404 means url not found (invalid url)  so it's wont' return anything

Comment: Yes, you must be right. I just wanted to use about "no user found" with wrong credentials. I never can try 400, 401, 404. Its like all forbidden in Retrofit

Comment: no , 400 - bad request , 401  - unauthorized, 404 - Not found, 422 - forbidden